# Migrating to iCloud when I sync with an Exchange account in Outlook

Tags: windows, icloud, ms-office, exchange-activesync

What happens to Microsoft Exchange accounts accessed in Outlook on a Windows machine when one migrates to iCloud? Will I lose that anything when I go to iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud has nothing to do with existing Exchange accounts. The only way one "migrates" to iCloud is if you have a MobileMe account. So you can enable iCloud without any impact on your Exchange account.